# Windows C# BLE connection stays open after process is killed

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

folks. I've got a BLE connection to a device, and I've discovered the services, characteristics, and descriptors, and I've registered for indications. All works fine.

BUT

While I'm receiving me indication values, one per second... if I KILL the client process - it's a console app so I just close it - the connection stays open. I know it's still open because the remote is my own device, and I can see the status on a serial monitor.

Win BLE provides no way to force close, even if I were to use DeviceWatcher to go find the connected device. Which I wouldn't want to do anyway, since I'm using the advertisement API and not DeviceWatcher.

I shouldn't need to force close anyway, because the *process is gone*.

I need to close this connection, or have it successfully close on its own. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve it? How are you discovering services using the advertisement API, I am struggling to find documentation on that. Since the bluetooth connection process is managed by Windows and is not linked to your process specifically you would need to close the connection if you don't want to keep it.